# Loop overlay input video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I use `ffmpeg` command to overlay one video over the other.
The shortest `in2.mp4` is 30s and I would like to repeat it until the longest `in1.avi` stops. With the following command, shortest is overlaid once and longest continues until its end.

```
ffmpeg -i in1.avi -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[top];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, format=yuva420p, colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=0" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

I have tried to place `loop=-1` in various places after `-filter_complex` but get an error

```
No such filter: 'loop' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument
```

Complete output:

```
ffmpeg -i in1.avi -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[top];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, format=yuva420p, colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5,loop=-1[bottom]; [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=0" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)   configuration: --enable-gpl
--enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100   libavcodec     56. 60.100 /
56. 60.100   libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101   libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100   libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101   libswresample   1.  2.101 / 
1.  2.101   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100 Input #0, avi, from 'in1.avi':   Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.32.100   Duration: 00:03:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 160 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in2.mp4':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2016-11-05 17:25:45   Duration: 00:00:15.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4071 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3815 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-11-05 17:25:45
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 255 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-11-05 17:25:45
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler [AVFilterGraph @ 056a41e0] No such filter: 'loop' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument
```

Comment: Show the complete console output instead of just the error for your command using the loop filter. Your ffmpeg must be old: libvo_aacenc was removed from ffmpeg some time ago because it was crappy.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard added output.

Comment: Apparently your ffmpeg is too old for the loop filter. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to static builds for Linux, macOS, and Windows. You'll need to chain `setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` after the loop filter to generate sane timestamps and you can then remove the `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`  from that same filterchain. You'll also need `format=yuv420p` after overlay. But deal with the old ffmpeg before doing anything else.

Comment: Ok, got it updated and now it does not throw an error for loop. Taken in things you mentioned here. Still does not repeat the shorter video. Command: `ffmpeg -i in1.avi -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[top];[1:v]loop=-1, setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB, scale=1920x1080, format=yuva420p, colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=0, format=yuv420p" out.mp4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `ffmpeg` was too old for the loop filter.
2. [loop](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop) requires you to tell it how many frames to loop.
3. Use `overlay=shortest=1` or it will loop forever.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i in1.avi -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex
  "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[top];
   [1:v]loop=-1:size=750, setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB, scale=1920x1080, format=yuva420p, colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom];
   [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1, format=yuv420p"
out.mp4
```

Comment: Why is it 75fps? (I assume you got 2250 = 75 x 30s)

Comment: @JanisS. That was a typo. Fixed. I originally put in 75 as an arbitrary value.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, do you have any idea about [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1294175/474942)

Comment: @AshkanNourzadeh Looks like you already got an answer-comment, so use `-loop 1` instead of loop filter as suggested.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, yeah that works and I use it to do the job, But I'm looking for the loop filter issue, I want to understand what is happening. And any help for that is appreciated.

Comment: I have already used **shortest=1** still my command goes into infinite loop.Error is : **Invalid PNG Signature**

Comment: @BhargavVariya You should post a new question. Make sure to show your command and the complete log.